# Load Balancing & High Availability Network Limitations

Tags: load-balancing, reverse-proxy, linux-networking, haproxy, high-availability

I'm in the process of coming up with a highly available Apache / MySql group of virtual servers using HAProxy Reverse Proxy & Keepalive.

I'm aware that I'm going to be using a floating public ip, then configuring HAProxy to relay traffic to the servers in the configuration file.

As far as I understand, all server instances need to be on the same network, this is a problem as if the datacenter does down, the group of servers fails. How can I create a highly available setup that does not require all virtual servers to be under one single network. I assume the problem will lie on the floating ip and HAProxy.

For example:

2 servers on Digital Ocean
2 servers on Linode
2 servers on aws

Digital Ocean specifies on this [page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-highly-available-web-servers-with-keepalived-and-floating-ips-on-ubuntu-14-04) "Both servers must be located within the same datacenter and should have private networking enabled."

They are using keepalive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to handle multi-site fail over is to have a pair of load balancers on site A in a master/slave fail over config. Then put an identical pair on the remote site.

If ALL the backend servers on site A fail then use the public VIP on site B as the fallback (high latencey of course across the WAN)... But back this up with a proper DNS based load balancing services such as Amazon route 53 (which has health checking and fail over) , So that fairly quickly no traffic would go to site A anyway.

If you have a really fast stretched VLAN across two sites with the same IP scheme then you can do it with just a single pair of load balancers.

But it sounds like you should just forget HAProxy and use Amazon Route 53 for the whole lot? (unless you have persistence issues.)

Comment: I'll look into Amazon Route 53, sounds like it should work perfectly as solution for multi-site. I really don't need load balancing, but high availability, your solution nails it. Thanks for the explanation. You're right, there will be latency across the WAN. I wonder how the big guys achieve high availability across many data center / sites / clustering, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can also "simulate" the local network by doing iptables redirect from a local machine to remote cloud.